# Solving a 2nd-order ODE via Eigenvectors/values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to solve $x'' - 8 x'+ 25 x = 0$. I found the general solution as $Ae^{4t}cos(3t) + Be^{4t}sin(3t)$, where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants.

However, when I write the differential equation as an equivalent first order system using the substitution y(t)=x′(t), I get the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix} x'\\y' \end{bmatrix} =$ $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{25}{9} &\frac{1}{9}\cr
-25 &-8\cr
\end{array}\right] \begin{bmatrix} x\\y \end{bmatrix}$.

I get this answer because

$\begin{aligned} x' = -y' -25 \\ y' = -8x' - 25x \end{aligned}$ and $\begin{aligned} x' = -(8x'-25x) + y \\ y' = -25x - 8y \end{aligned}$

$\begin{aligned} 9x' = 25x + y \\ y' = -25x - 8y \end{aligned}$ which implies
$\begin{aligned} x' = \dfrac{25}{9} + \dfrac{y}{9} \\ y' = -25x - 8y \end{aligned}$.

However, this is apparently incorrect.

Any help would be appreciated as to what I did wrong.

Here's a snapshot of the question I'm working on.

[image]

Comment: You have defined $y = x'$, so the first equation is $x' = 0x + 1y$. And $y' = x'' = 8x' - 25 x = 8y - 25 x$. Together $$\begin{pmatrix} x'\\ y'\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -25 & 8\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ahh I see the trick you used there. Thank you.

I am not struggling to find the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda = 4 \pm 3i$. Can you please direct me?

Comment: Well, you subtract $\lambda I$ from the matrix and determine the kernel. Here it's particularly simple due to the form of the first row, we get $\begin{pmatrix} -\lambda & 1\end{pmatrix}$ as the first row, so a corresponding eigenvector is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \lambda\end{pmatrix}$.